# Tagapalooza: {tables} and {horizontal-align}

Tags: discussion, tagging, tagwiki

[tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) wiki reads at the moment:

> [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) is about the `tabular` environment and related packages
>   such as [array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array), [booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/booktabs), [tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabularx) and
>   [longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longtable). For questions about the `table` environment (i.e.,
>   about floating or positioning), use [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats) instead.
>
> There are many packages that extend the basic functionality of the
>   `tabular` environment. A good overview of packages (and package
>   conflicts) can be found in
>   [Which tabular packages do which tasks and which packages conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict/12673#12673).
>
> If your question involves one of these specific packages (or another
>   tabular package not listed), you should add a tag for that package as
>   well as the [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) tag.

So a LaTeX-specific wiki as it stands. All of the above relate to horizontal alignment. I think I've always tagged `\halign` questions with [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment), and so was wondering what purpose does the [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) tag represent since it outrules `table` (for [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats)), and isn't specifically about [tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabular) (since its name is [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) and not [tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabular)).  On the one hand, `\halign` questions could be in [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) just as well as [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) could be [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment). It should be noted that `tabular` uses `\halign` internally, and `\halign` comes from “horizontal alignment”.

To me it would seem logical if [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) was a synonym for [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment), and for actual `tabular` questions there would be a tag [tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabular).

What do you think?

---

Speaking of [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment), I find the current wiki rather confusing:

> [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment) is about aligning document elements horizontally, e.g. typesetting paragraphs using `\centering` or `\raggedright` or adjusting the horizontal position of several equation or table components. If your question is generally about (horizontal) white space, use [spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacing) instead.

, because, as I understand, neither `\centering`, nor `\raggedright` actually **align** anything.

Maybe those two could fit into a tag like [paragraph-shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragraph-shape) or similar?

Comment: @N.N.: Thanks! May I ask how did you do that?

Comment: Try to edit your post again and you will see the syntax. Tags on the main site are linked to by `[tag:tagname]`. I merely copied the actual markup from the tag and then to correct the remaining tags I searched and replaced to get from `{` to `[tag:` and from `}` to `]` (search and replace I did in an external editor).

Answer (score 3):

[tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) isn't called [tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabular) because it also covers questions about similar environments like [tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabularx) and [tabulary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabulary). The tag is about aligning table elements, but also about spacing, adding captions and rules, dealing with multi-column and multi-row areas etc.

`\raggedright` is about aligning paragraphs to the left margin of the text block. An alternative name for [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment) would have been "justification", but the former name corresponds to [vertical-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment) (which is, e.g., about `\raggedbottom`).

Comment: Yeah OK, I *was about to* add “…unless you count aligning to the left margin as align”, but then I thought that's pretty much given.